# ¿Como puedo comprobar si existe un dato en una tabla SQLITE y mostrar error en caso contrario?

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

No soy capaz de que aparezca un mensaje de error en caso de que no haya resultados en SQLite.

El código es el siguiente:

```
     try:
        miConexion=sqlite3.connect("Clientes.db")
        miCursor=miConexion.cursor()
        miCursor.execute("select * from DATOSCLIENTE WHERE NOMBRE LIKE '"+var_dato.get()+"%'")
        cliente=miCursor.fetchall()
        var_observaciones.delete('1.0',END)
        #MUestra los resultado en una tabla
        for row in cliente:
                tree.insert("",0,text=row[0], values=(row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5]))
        miConexion.commit()
    except:
        messagebox.showerror("N","Se ha producido un error en la búsqueda")
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas tardes le comento:

No tiene por qué usarse try/catch y además es una mala práctica.

Para que aparezca un mensaje de error en caso de que no haya resultados es tan simple como validar que la variable que contiene los datos sea igual a [].

Esto sería en su caso una demostración de lo que intento decir:

```
if cliente==[]:
      print("ERROR. No hay datos de clientes")
else:
      print("RESULTADOS:")
      for i in cliente:
          print(i) # ASÍ PUES SE IMPRIME CADA CAMPO UNO POR UNO O COMO LO QUIERA HACER
```

Espero que le sea de utilidad. Un saludo

Comment: Ya probé, lo que intento es que si no hay resultados en la búsqueda, muestre el mensaje de error.